# Is there a way to populate a RecyclerView row with more than one ViewHolder object? What should the adapter implement?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am implementing a recycler view with two ViewHolder types. After creating the first item as first-type view holder, I have a list of items of the same, second type. Now, I would like to juxtapose the second type items in order to define a two-column recycler view list considering the second type. Is it possible to do that? I have no idea of what should be implemented in the adapter and honestly I have found no good suggestions here. I guess I might not post my adapter code, since I don't know whether it is possible to do what I aim, I hope a conceptual answer may be sufficient too. I have an image, made with a not good image editor of my smartphone, I hope it is clear:

[image]

Comment: What you are seeking for is a Recyclerview with a nested Recyclerview.

Comment: I didn't know we can nest RecyclerView(s). I am going to look for a good solution and if I cannot find it, I would appreciate any effort to help me. In this case, I would post my (very simple) adapter code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am late but I found out a solution.
I associate to the recyclerview a GridLayoutManager with span count = 2.
Since I have, at the top of the recyclerview, an EditText (I use it as a search bar), as you can see in the image, I have to set the lookup of the grid. This is done by setSpanSizeLookup(). So, **in the onViewCreated() method of my fragment class that initializes the recyclerview** (I have a Fragment hosting the recyclerview), I insert the following code:

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            int type = adapter.getItemViewType(position);
            if (type == RecyclerAdapter.SEARCH)
                return 2;
            else
                return 1;
        }
    });

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

where the part "if (type == RecyclerAdapter.SEARCH) return 2;" means that the view holder for the search bar is going to occupy one whole row, 2 grid cells (since the span = 2).

In my recyclerview adapter, the method getItemViewType is essential:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0)
        return SEARCH;
    else
        return DESCRIPTION;
}
```

where SEARCH and DESCRIPTION are two static final variables.